# Regex for a word at the beginning of a line with trailing whitespace

Tags: regex, awk

I have the following line:

```
    given some books I've given to my son.
```

Notice the four spaces in front of the "Given". I want to match the "given" following whitespace at the beginning of the line with a regex. I do not want the second "given" to match.

If I use `\s*given` it will match both words. If I add the `^` for the beginning of the line (`^\s*given`) it does not match either.

Try to enter `\s*The` and `^\s*The` on this [RegexOne example](http://regexone.com/example/5) to understand the problem.

### Edit

For some reason, the fox example works now and the regex works on another site, so here's my full example:

```
  given an egg
    and some milk
    and the ingredient flour
   when the cook mangles everything to a dough
    and the cook fries the dough in a pan
   then the resulting meal is a pan cake
```

And my awk expressions that all don't match:

```
/^\s*given/ { print "given()."}
/^[\s]*and/ { print "and()."}
/^\s*when/ { print "when()."}
/^\s*then/ { print "then()."}
```

They all match once I remove the `^`.

Comment: Please check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJ8lW3/1). Isn't it what you need?

Comment: It is. Why is it working in that demo and not in awk and on the RegexOne site? :-(

Comment: If you type `^\s*The` on RegexOne, you will get the first `The` highlighted. It works there.  It is actually correct and is what you need.

Comment: Yes. This leaves me even more confused. I've updated the question with the real life example.

Comment: `grep -oP '^\s*\K\w*'`, `awk '{print $1}'`, `sed 's/\s*\(\S*\).*/\1/'` … everyone is work. Try to pass lines through `hd -c` to see if there are `\s` on the begining

Comment: I don't want to match the first word, I want to match the words "given", "and", "when" and "then".

Comment: `\s` is shorthand for the POSIX `[[:space:]]`. The former is only supported in a few awks. If it doesn't work in your awk then use the latter.

Comment: `\s*given` works, `^\s*given` doesn't :-s.

Comment: If you have that text in a file, try `awk '{
        for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                tmp=match($i, /^[[:blank:]]*[[:alpha:]]+/)
                if(tmp) {
                        print $i
                }
        }
}' $1`

Answer (score 2):

As Ed Morton mentioned, some Awks (such as [The One True Awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk)) only support POSIX character classes, so `\s` is not matching whitespace, it's matching the letter `s`.

Since you're using `*` to match zero or more occurrences:

```
awk '/\s*given/' file
```

matches because there are zero occurrences of `s` at the beginning of the line, whereas:

```
awk '/^\s*given/' file
```

will never match because there are unmatched characters (whitespace) between `^` (start of line) and the word `given`.

If you were to use `+` to match *one* or more occurrences, you'd see that this does not work either:

```
awk '/\s+given/' file
```

so the obvious solution is to use `[[:space:]]`:

```
awk '/^[[:space:]]*given/' file
```

But since Awk's default is to split fields by whitespace, if you wish to match a word against the first set of non-whitespace characters, it's more straight forward to compare the word with the first field `$1`.

```
awk '$1 == "given"' file
```

to match completely, or:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^given/' file
```

to match against the beginning of the first field.

As an aside, if you want to test your regex against a set of words and print them appended with `().`, as is shown in your example, you could use the [string functions](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html) `match` and `substr` like this:

```
awk '{
    m = match($0, /^[[:space:]]*(given|and|when|then)/) # or match($1, /.../)
    if(m)
        print substr($1, RSTART, RSTART+RLENGTH) "()."
}' file
```

output:

```
given.()
and.()
and.()
when.()
and.()
then.()
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex can match what you're looking for:

```
^[[:space:]]*given
```

It matches all the whitespace characters in the front including the first "given".

You can play with it here:

https://regex101.com/r/yA5dV0/1

---

Edit: Changed it to Ed Morton's suggestion.

Comment: A "regexp" is close to useless without which tool handles that regexp as desired. Most awks, for example, would treat that regexp as a start-of-string, then a letter `s` repeated 0 or more times, and then the word `given` and some of them would warn you about the useless escape char before the `s`, That's probably not what the OP wants.